# Optional conditions in postgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a procedure with optional arguments and use them only if they are not null

My current query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM sth WHERE
  (arg1 IS NULL OR sth.c1 = arg1) AND
  (arg2 IS NULL OR sth.c2 = arg2) AND
  (arg3 IS NULL OR sth.c3 > arg3) AND
  (arg4 IS NULL OR sth.c4 < arg4)
```

I'm thinking of a way to make it look better / shorter. My first shot is:

```
SELECT * FROM sth WHERE
  COALESCE(sth.c1 = arg1, 't') AND
  COALESCE(sth.c2 = arg2, 't') AND
  COALESCE(sth.c3 > arg3, 't') AND
  COALESCE(sth.c4 < arg4, 't');
```

but I'm not sure if this looks any better. Do you know any useful tricks for this?

Comment: ``something = something`` is either ``true`` or ``false``, not NULL

Comment: @nrathaus: `anything = NULL` is null

Comment: The first form is probably clearer, and lets the optimiser cut the expressions out entirely by proving the other side of the `OR` is always true. Though the planner might be able to prove that `[anything] = NULL` is always `NULL` too; I haven't checked; you should be able to tell in `explain` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it the way it is. Using coalesce will prevent the query planner from doing its job properly, and you'll end up with sucky query plans.

Best I'm aware, the following expressions will use a btree index:

- `col = 'val'`
- `col is null`

The following expressions will not use a btree index:

- `col is [not] 'val'`
- `(col = 'val') is [not] <true | false | null>`
- `col is [not] distinct from 'val'`
- `coalesce(col, 'val') = 'val'`
- `coalesce(col = 'val', <true | false | null>)`

Comment: how about my updated query? Will the query planner work correctly in that case?

Comment: Insofar as I'm aware, your first one is the only one it'll try to optimize. The one showed by @Adassko may look a bit better, but the use of the IS operator is a bit like using COALESCE: the planner will usually yield a seq scan. With your original query, it should at least do a bitmap index scan, and chances are it'll actually get prepared differently (and properly, as in simplified) depending on your input parameter.

Comment: but isn't the `IS` operator used in the first query as well?

Comment: @Denis The planner does optimize through `COALESCE`; `coalesce('not-null', (SELECT ...))` will never even plan the subquery. I'm not sure it proves that `x = NULL` is always `NULL` and avoids evaluating the first term, though.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I'm curious to know where or how… both `select * from test where coalesce(id, 5) = 5` and `select * from test where coalesce(id = 5, true)` yield a seq scan in 9.3.1.

Comment: @Denis It may only be true where the first input is a non-null constant, not an expression. `coalesce` can be optimized out, but the `id` test might not be, and if it can't be optimized out it can't be used for a non-function-scan btree search.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think that this query is the best idea for this purpose

```
SELECT * FROM sth WHERE
  NOT (sth.c1 = arg1) IS FALSE AND
  NOT (sth.c2 = arg2) IS FALSE AND
  NOT (sth.c3 > arg3) IS FALSE AND
  NOT (sth.c4 < arg4) IS FALSE;
```

it doesn't use any functions so the query planner *should* work fine just as before

it just uses simple expressions where:

```
1.
true = true // true
true = false // false
true = null // null

2.
false is false // true
true is false // false
null is false // false

3.
not true // false
not false // true
```

so it will return `true` if expression is `true` OR `null`

Comment: In PG 9.3, `explain analyze select * from test where not(id = 5) is false` => seq scan + filter. `explain analyze select * from test where id = 5 or 5 is null` => index scan.